# How to limit THREE.TransformControls to have only positive values for scale

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to for the scale gizmo  (THREE.TransformControls) to have only positive values ? 
Negative values causes the model to turn inside-out.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: goto TransformControls.js and

replace

```
var newScaleX = oldScale.x * ( 1 + point.x / oldScale.x );
var newScaleY = oldScale.y * ( 1 + point.y / oldScale.y );
var newScaleZ = oldScale.z * ( 1 + point.z / oldScale.z );

point.applyMatrix4( tempMatrix.getInverse( worldRotationMatrix ) );

if ( scope.axis === "X" ) scope.object.scale.x = newScaleX;
if ( scope.axis === "Y" ) scope.object.scale.y = newScaleY;
if ( scope.axis === "Z" ) scope.object.scale.z = newScaleZ;
```

with

```
var newScaleX = oldScale.x * ( 1 + point.x / oldScale.x );
var newScaleY = oldScale.y * ( 1 + point.y / oldScale.y );
var newScaleZ = oldScale.z * ( 1 + point.z / oldScale.z );

point.applyMatrix4( tempMatrix.getInverse( worldRotationMatrix ) );

if (newScaleX>0)
    if ( scope.axis === "X" ) scope.object.scale.x = newScaleX;
if (newScaleY>0)
    if ( scope.axis === "Y" ) scope.object.scale.y = newScaleY;
if (newScaleZ>0)
    if ( scope.axis === "Z" ) scope.object.scale.z = newScaleZ;
```